# I am getting this error message while installing ubuntu on virtual box?

Tags: software-installation

```
Not in a hypervisor partition (HVP=0) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).


Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

what does it mean and how should i solve it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304393/vt-x-is-disabled-in-the-bios-for-both-all-cpu-modes-verr-vmx-msr-all-vmx-disabl

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable virtualization in the BIOS.

Turn off your machine, turn it back on and enter the BIOS by tapping whichever button is required at the first splash screen, and then enable virtualization.

Most of the time the options for virtualization are under a section specific to the Processor.

If you mention the make/model of your machine then I can help you find out exactly how to enter the BIOS and which settings to enable